# DBContext is not recognized in Visual Studio 2012 Express for Web

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, dbcontext

1. I have installed Visual Studio 2012 Express for Web, licensed it
2. Created new Basic MVC 4 web application. It's a simple bookstore website example
3. Added connection to SQL Server Express 2008 database. There are already 3 linked tables in it
4. Created a new model for Books table
5. As you see on the screenshot, I tried to add a data context exactly like it is in all tutorials but for some reason it doesn't recognize DBContext class. Nowhere is said to create this class manually so I assume it should be in System.Data.Entity...

Why doesn't it recognize that class?

[image]

Comment: Have you added a reference to Entity Framework? https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework

Comment: Not sure if it makes difference but try `DbContext` not `DBContext`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `DbContext` not `DBContext`:

> A **DbContext** instance represents a combination of the Unit Of Work and
>   Repository patterns such that it can be used to query from a database
>   and group together changes that will then be written back to the store
>   as a unit. DbContext is conceptually similar to ObjectContext.

See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext(v=vs.113).aspx) for reference.